# Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/contacts: 405 OK

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on a project involving an authenticated `put` request, however it presents the following error:

```
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 405,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "https://localhost:5001/api/contacts",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/contacts: 405 OK",
    "error": null
}
```

html:

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 50%">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <!--FIRST NAME-->
          <div class="row g-2"></div>
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
          <label class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="!firstname.value && firstname.touched">
            First Name is
            required
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--LAST NAME-->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <label class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="!lastname.value && lastname.touched">
          Last Name is
          required
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Email Address-->
    <label></label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <label class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="!emailaddress.value && emailaddress.touched">
      Email Address is
      required
    </label>
    <!--Primary Phone Number-->
    <label></label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="primaryphonenumber" placeholder="Primary Phone Number" />
    <label class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="!primaryphonenumber.value && primaryphonenumber.touched">
      Primary Phone Number is
      required
    </label>
    <!--Secondary Phone Number-->
    <label></label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="secondaryphonenumber" placeholder="Secondary Phone Number" />
    <!--Address-->
    <label></label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="address" placeholder="Address" />
    <label class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="!address.value && address.touched">
      Address is
      required
    </label>
    <!--Type-->
    <label class="mt-5"></label>
    <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="type" id="drop-downmenu">
      <label for="drop-downmenu">Type of Contact</label>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types" [value]="t.typeValue" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">{{t.caption}} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4" (click)="Update()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

edit component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactTypes } from '../contact-types';
import { ContactService } from '../contact.service';
import { IContact } from '../icontact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  firstname: FormControl;
  lastname: FormControl;
  emailaddress: FormControl;
  primaryphonenumber: FormControl;
  secondaryphonenumber: FormControl;
  address: FormControl;
  type: FormControl;
  types: any[] = ContactTypes.getContactTypes();

  form: FormGroup;

  contact: IContact;

  constructor(private contactservice: ContactService, private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private activatesRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {

    this.form = this.BuildForm();
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.activatesRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.contact = await this.contactservice.getContact(id);
    this.firstname.setValue(this.contact.firstName);
    this.lastname.setValue(this.contact.lastName);
    this.emailaddress.setValue(this.contact.emailAddress);
    this.primaryphonenumber.setValue(this.contact.primaryPhoneNumber);
    this.secondaryphonenumber.setValue(this.contact.secondaryPhoneNumber);
    this.address.setValue(this.contact.address);
    this.type.setValue(this.contact.type);

    console.log(this.contact);
    console.log(id);
  }

  BuildForm(): FormGroup {
    this.firstname = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.lastname = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.emailaddress = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.primaryphonenumber = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.secondaryphonenumber = new FormControl('');
    this.address = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.type = new FormControl(0);

    return this.formbuilder.group({
      firstname: this.firstname,
      lastname: this.lastname,
      emailaddress: this.emailaddress,
      primaryphonenumber: this.primaryphonenumber,
      secondaryphonenumber: this.secondaryphonenumber,
      address: this.address,
      type: this.type
    });
  }
  
  async Update(): Promise<void> {
    const newcontact: IContact = {
      id: this.contact.id,
      firstName: this.firstname.value,
      lastName: this.lastname.value,
      emailAddress: this.emailaddress.value,
      primaryPhoneNumber: this.primaryphonenumber.value,
      secondaryPhoneNumber: this.secondaryphonenumber.value,
      address: this.address.value,
      type: this.type.value
    }

    try {
      const contact = await this.contactservice.editContact(newcontact);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
  } 
}
```

service

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {IContact} from './icontact';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  private readonly URL: string;
  private readonly CONTROLLER = 'api/contacts'
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL')private baseUrl: string) {
    this.URL = `${this.baseUrl}${this.CONTROLLER}`
  }

  async getContacts(): Promise<IContact[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IContact[]>(this.URL).toPromise();
  }

  async getContact(id: number): Promise<IContact> {
    const url = `${this.URL}/${id}`;

    return this.httpClient.get<IContact>(url).toPromise();
  }

  async addContact(contact: IContact): Promise<IContact> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IContact>(this.URL, contact).toPromise();
  }

  async editContact(contact: IContact): Promise<IContact> {
    return this.httpClient.put<IContact>(this.URL, contact).toPromise();
  }

  async deleteContact(contact: IContact): Promise<IContact> {
    const url = `${this.URL}/${contact.id}`;

    return this.httpClient.delete<IContact>(this.URL).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: looks like PUT method is not allowed in your backend part

Comment: [405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)